# awk + print from the third field until end of line each word with one space

Tags: awk

How do I print all $Organs words (from the third field) with one space between each Organ to another?  My problem is that each $Organ param have different Organs number so I cant to guess the last field number.  I need awk syntax that print the $Organs param from the third field until the last field with one space between the word.

```
Organs="a bb c ddd ee ff rr ff"
Organs="1 2    3 4 5   6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 20 21 22"
Organs="I need to lern awk I hope I will do the best"
Organs="I need help"


echo $Organs| awk '{print $3" "$4" "$5" "$6 .......?}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% echo $Organs | awk '{              \
       for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {   \
          printf("%s ", $i);         \
       }                             \
       printf("\n") }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++)
    printf("%s ", $i);
print ""
```

NF gives you the number of fields in the line. Take a look at this FAQ:

- http://hibernia.jakma.org/~paul/awk-faq.html

Agree better suited for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This outputs a field per line, use `printf` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
  $1=$2=""  # suppress first two fields
  out=substr($0, 3)  # suppress the two leading occurrences of OFS that remain
  print out
}'
```

This assumes that OFS evaluates to a single space, which is its default value.

This solution may be a bit faster than the others. It conceivably could be slower, too: it depends on whether it's faster to reassign fields and reparse `$0`, as this solution does, or to implement an awk loop, as the other solutions do. But you're not going to notice the speed difference, either way.